# MouseEvent in QGridLayout

Tags: qt

Trying to implement drag & drop functionality from QGridLayout to QGraphicsScene.

QGridLayout has labels inside of it and I am trying to move them. Is it possible to listen QGridLayout mouse events and get the specific label. With JavaFX this was quite easy to do, but with Qt feels much harder.

Comment: QGridLayout is not a visual element so it does not handle mouse events.

Comment: @eyllanesc Aight, if we ignore that part of it. Is there a method to find the label by mouse event pos?

Comment: Use an eventFilter or create a class that inherits from QLabel and override the mouseXEvent methods (In SO there are thousands of examples), on the other hand do not compare libraries (do not think that Qt behaves the same as JavaFX)

Comment: @eyllanesc Solved! Because the class is subclass of QWidget. I was able to get the label by childAt(...)